# Store large number in a cell with PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I need to store a 24 digits number in a cell with PHPExcel.
I've read some tutorials about that. But the problem still exists...

Here is the code:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A2', '680540101947000270348604');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C2', '100');
```

It supposed to store entire number without any change. But when I open file it's stored like:

> 6.80540101947E23

I tried also to save that as an string and that worked. But I have to deliver this file to bank so their system is so stupid and does't accept number as string...They need to calculate I guess.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
// Set the value explicitly as a string
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('A2', '680540101947000270348604', PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

Comment: According to the last lines of question, Is there any way to save entire number as TEXT?

Comment: Yes I did. The same code in your answer. That turns input to string but I need it to be text.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set cell format as text then it will be possible.

```
$objPHPExcel
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```